# C# Flag Charlie-Fox

Tags: c#, c++, boolean

I've been trying to emulate in C# a behavior which I was implementing without any problems in C++. I have a flag collection, which based on powers of 2, and a flag which I need to check if it exists in the collection.

```
  byte flagCollection = 1 | 2 | 4 | 8;
  byte flag = 2;

  if ((flagCollection & flag) != 0) MessageBox.Show("y"); else MessageBox.Show("n");
```

Now, the problem is that whatever I set Flag to (2, 3, 100, 211), I always get "y", except for 0. Of course, 1, 2, 4, 8 would be some constants which have various meanings in my application.

In C++:

```
if (flagCollection & flag)
```

Would result in TRUE for the variables above.

Comment: What I wanted to do is check if a flag OR A COLLECTION of flags is present. Forgot to mention that, sorry. The solution Andrey gave me worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it seems correct. I'm not really sure what behavior you are expecting. Any of the flags you listed (2, 3, 100, 211) do contain an element of 1 | 2 | 4 | 8. If you want to check whether *all* of them are present you should be doing

```
if ((flagCollection & flag) == flag) 
   // ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to do actually.

Comment: One more thing, just to be sure... the == flag part is required only because we're in C#, right? Because in C++ it works without that. But there's that entire discussion about Boolean & int in C# which requires us to add the == flag, is this correct?

Comment: Nope, in C++ you'd have to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

well, if you're flag collection has OR'd 1,2,4,8, uh yes I think every positive integer that's not a multiple of 16 when &'d to it is going to return something. Or am I missing something?

Comment: C# behavior confused me. It acts a bit different that C++. What I wanted to do is to check if a certain flag OR COMBINATION of flags is within the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
[Flag]
public enum flagCollection {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type4,
  Type8,
}

flagCollection testValue = flagCollection.Type2

if ((testValue & flagCollection.Type2) == flagCollection.Type2) {
   MessageBox.Show("y");
} else {
   MessageBox.Show("n");
}
```

Not in front of the compiler so cant chek if that will work or not.

Comment: Yeah, that works, except it's "Flags" not "Flag", the compiler complained about it in the "if" instruction. Didn't know about that attribute. Thank you! ::- ).

Comment: You also need to assign values explicitly to the enum elements, because even if you decorate the enum with `Flags` the values assigned automatically are still 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: *laugh* that's weird. I imagined that's EXACTLY why the Flags attribute is there. If it doesn't do that, then why use it in the first place? Strange. I looked in MSDN and they only say "Indicates that an enumeration can be treated as a bit field; that is, a set of flags.". Ok, now that they told me that, I can sleep well *laugh*.

Comment: I thought Flags automatically did binary shifting on a value. LOL! Learn omething new ever day.